# Python: Issues with plotting points using a loop. Exponential Decay of throwing 100 di

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib

This is less of a code related issue and more of a failure in logic of the plotting system, or so I believe. 
Here is my code

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

N = int(input('Enter Total Number Of Dice: '))
S = int(input('Enter Number of Sides on Each Dice: '))

xval = []
yval = []
count = 0
max1 = N
xval.append(0)
yval.append(N)
numOfTurns = 1
while(N != 0):
    for i in range(0, N):
        x = random.randint(1 , S)
        count = 0
        if(N == max1 / 2):
            plt.axvline(numOfTurns ,color = 'k', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 1.5)
        if(x == 1):
          count+=1
          N -= count
    yval.append(N)
    xval.append(numOfTurns)
    numOfTurns += 1


plt.plot(xval, yval, 'b')
plt.xlabel('Number Of Turns')
plt.ylabel('Number Of Dice') 
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The error arises with my x-axis in that my points make no logical sense I believe the error lies within the IF statement in the for loop -> More specifically the N -= count. although this has no direct relation to the points plotted along the x axis is does control how quickly the loop ends. As such it then limits the variable numOfTurns. Here is a screen capture of the graph with the values of N = 100 and S = 6: https://gyazo.com/eb2965eda014d4a69ceb36142ebd1902    The odd thing is when I use the value for the half life of the curve to find the decay constant in the equation l = ln(2)/Half Life Where l is the decay constant i get ~0.17 which is pretty close to 1/6 which is the answer you'd expect. Sorry if this branchs too far into physics/mathematics.

Also I originally made this code in C# (Which is working):

```
int NumberOfSixes = 0;
            int TurnNO = 0;
            Random dice = new Random();
            int max = 100;
            do
            {
                for (int i = 100; i >-1; i -= NumberOfSixes)
                {
                    int value = dice.Next(1, 6);
                    if (value == 1)
                    {
                        NumberOfSixes++;
                    }
                }

                this.eChart.Series["e^1"].Points.AddXY(TurnNO, max - NumberOfSixes);
                TurnNO++;
            }
            while (NumberOfSixes != 100);
```

Here is the screen capture of the graph for the c# Results (Note the difference in the x-axis) - https://gyazo.com/1ae3afb9198063416ffeed87f0873daa There is a clear inconsistency.

Comment: So you are trying to port code?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem: "my points make no logical sense" is not specific.  Yes, I see that the graphs are different: your C# program appears incorrect, in that it takes about 60 time periods to achieve the half-life threshold, but the Python version does it in the expected 4.  I don't see how this makes the Python points non-sensical.